# Where can I find the ground truth labels of a ILSVRC2012 high level category, for example animals?

Tags: python, caffe, label

I'm using the ILSVRC2012 dataset and for that, I have the ground_truth_labels and the synset_words.txt. Now, I access [this](http://image-net.org/synset?wnid=n02119789) and download just the images containing animals.

I use a neural network to make a prediction and now, I want to calculate the classification error but I don't have the ground truth labels.

**My question is**: where can I find the ground truth labels for these images? The name of them appear like this

n00015388_12.JPEG,

n00015388_24.JPEG,

n00015388_119.JPEG

Is there any relationship between the name of the images and the files given by caffe? (synset_word.txt and val.txt)

What's the meaning of the numbers used to name the images?

Answer (score 0):

The main correlation is that the directory (the **n00015388** part) maps uniquely to the label: There will be ~1300 images that share that prefix.

I haven't yet found a correlation between the suffix (such as _119) and the file use.  The suffix is unique within each class, of course.  However, the quantity of each suffix varies quite a bit.

If you want to investigate on your own, there's a complete list of files in your generated **train.txt** file, generated by one of the setup scripts -- or easy enough to generate from a "ls" file listing and header information.

Comment: The n00015388 part appears in all images of animals in Validation Set on ILSVRC2012. Besides the knowledge that the image contains an animal, I already have my predictions but I need the ground truth labels to compute the classification error. I searched in synset_words.txt the n00015388 and I got no match. It's possible that I downloaded images by categories from ilsvrc2011 and not the ilsvrc2012? I used this link: image-net.org/synset?wnid=n02119789